# How to use xml_output_stream and export to XML using Magik programming (Smallworld)

Tags: xml, magik

I am trying to export to XML using XML_output_stream using Magik programming which is a Smallworld language.

I have written the below code

```
    ws << xml_output_stream.new("N:\Laura\xml.feeder.magik.xml")
    
    _local dbs << gis_program_manager.databases
    _local elec_db << dbs[:electric]
    _local tbl_feeder << elec_db.collections[:eo_circuit]
    
_for k,v _over  tbl_feeder.elements()   
_loop

    ws.start_element(:feeder,k.nma_operational_level)
    ws.write_element("operational level", k.nma_operational_level)
    ws.end_element(:feeder,k.nma_operational_level)

_endloop
```

The code is running and giving me the following output, but no XML file is opening or in my folders

**Loading C:\Users\Laura\AppData\Local\Temp\17\TLaura2324q0
**** Emacs: buffer=feeder.magik file=n:/laura/feeder.magik position=1**

Has anyone else had this problem or am I entering something wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure why someone downvoted this. Smallworld is definitely GIS software and the question is fine as it contains code and includes expected and actual results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong method to create your output stream. The method `xml_output_stream.new()` expects an output stream as its first argument. You can find the relevant documentation in the class browser, or in the online manual chapter [Using the XML output stream](https://smallworld.gedigitalenergy.com/docs/sw53/en/swDocs5.htm#../Subsystems/AppDev/Content/ExternalCommunication/XMLOutputStream.htm) in case you're on Smallworld 5.

You probably want to use the method `xml_output_stream.new_file()` to construct the XML stream. That method accepts a filename/path to a file, rather than a stream.

The body of your loop should be updated as well. The method `xml_output_stream.start_element()` expects a `name` as its first argument (ok in your code), but the other arguments should be key-element-pairs where the key is the name of the attribute and the element is the value of the attribute.

Also, I think the value `"operational level"` for a tag will result in invalid XML. You can try replacing it with `:operational_level`, for example.